# É possível forçar um valor quando select não tiver resultado para pesquisa?

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom galera, tenho uma situação aonde preciso mostrar o saldo de faturamento por cliente, como não consegui de maneira nenhuma utilizar um select que junta o resultado de outros dois select, resolvi utilizar os resultados separados e efetuar a operação de subtração direto no ASP invés de usar o SQL para isso. Porém alguns clientes não tem valor a pagar, apenas a receber ou o contrario, e isso traz um grave problema no meu grid, clientes que não tem um desses valores herdam do anterior que tenha esse campo X preenchido. Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Cliente da linha de cima tem os dois valores corretos, porém o da segunda linha não tem esses 25 USD no sistema, apenas o outro valor.

O ponto é, isso acontece pois eu utilizo dois selects com base nos clientes que estão na listagem de faturas, é possível eu forçar um valor 0 quando o cliente não aparecer no select? Exemplo do select abaixo e código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
SELECT
  ID_CD_PESSOA,
  NM_PAGREC,
  COALESCE(SUM(COALESCE(VL_FATURA_TOTAL_MOEDA, 0)), 0) AS TOTAL_APAGAR,
  DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL
FROM (SELECT
  FATU.ID_CD_FATURA,
  FATU.ID_CD_BOOKING,
  FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA,
  FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE,
  FATU.ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO,
  FATU.IN_STATUS,
  FATU.ID_CD_FATURA_REL,
  NM_PAGREC = (SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN CRMP.IN_TIPO = 'F' THEN CRMP.NM_PESSOA + ' ' + CRMP.NM_SOBRENOME + '<br>' + CONVERT(varchar, CRMP.NR_CPF_CNPJ)
      ELSE CRMP.NM_APELIDO + '<br>' + CONVERT(varchar, CRMP.NR_CPF_CNPJ)
    END
  FROM TB_CRM_PESSOAS_CRMP CRMP
  WHERE ID_CD_PESSOA = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA
  OR ID_CD_PESSOA = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE),
  ID_CD_PESSOA = (SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN CRMP.IN_TIPO = 'F' THEN CRMP.ID_CD_PESSOA
      ELSE CRMP.ID_CD_PESSOA
    END
  FROM TB_CRM_PESSOAS_CRMP CRMP
  WHERE ID_CD_PESSOA = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA
  OR ID_CD_PESSOA = FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE) -- TIPO DE FATURA
  ,
  FATU.FL_CONV_MOEDA_BRL -- BOOKING
  ,
  BOOK.DS_AMS_REFERENCE -- ADICIONAIS
  ,
  TEM_FECHAMENTO.FL_TEM_FECHAMENTO,
  TEM_FECHAMENTO.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI -- FINANCEIRO
  ,
  TEM_LANCAMENTO.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO,
  TEM_LANCAMENTO.FL_COMPENSADO,
  COALESCE(VL_FATURA_TOTAL, 0) AS VL_FATURA_TOTAL,
  COALESCE(VL_FATURA_TOTAL_MOEDA, 0) AS VL_FATURA_TOTAL_MOEDA,
  DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL = (SELECT TOP (1)
    CASE
      WHEN FATU.ID_CD_QUEM_PAGA IS NOT NULL THEN FAIT.DS_MOEDA_VENDA
      ELSE FAIT.DS_MOEDA_CUSTO
    END DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL
  FROM TB_FATURA_ITENS_FAIT FAIT
  WHERE FAIT.ID_CD_FATURA = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA)
FROM TB_FATURA_FATU FATU
INNER JOIN TB_BOOKING_BOOK BOOK
  ON BOOK.ID_CD_BOOKING = FATU.ID_CD_BOOKING
INNER JOIN TB_FATURAS_TIPOS_FATP FATP
  ON FATP.ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO
INNER JOIN TB_LOGIN_LOGI LOGI
  ON LOGI.ID_CD_LOGIN = FATU.ID_CD_LOGIN
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
  FL_TEM_FECHAMENTO = 'S',
  FAPR2.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI
FROM TB_FATURA_AUX_FPAX FPAX2
INNER JOIN TB_FATURA_PRINCIPAL_FAPR FAPR2
  ON FAPR2.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI = FPAX2.ID_CD_FATURA_PRI
WHERE FPAX2.ID_CD_FATURA = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
AND FAPR2.IN_STATUS = 1) AS TEM_FECHAMENTO
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
  ID_CD_LANCAMENTO,
  FL_COMPENSADO = (SELECT TOP 1
    'N'
  FROM TB_FIN_LANCAMENTOS_PARC_FNLP FNLP2
  WHERE FNLP2.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO = FNLP.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO
  AND FNLP2.ID_CD_AUXILIAR = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
  AND FNLP2.FL_AUXILIAR = 'FAT'
  AND FNLP2.FL_SITUACAO = 'A'),
  DT_ULTIMO_PAGTO = (SELECT TOP 1
    FNLP3.DT_COMPENSADO
  FROM TB_FIN_LANCAMENTOS_PARC_FNLP FNLP3
  WHERE FNLP3.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO = FNLP.ID_CD_LANCAMENTO
  AND FNLP3.ID_CD_AUXILIAR = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
  AND FNLP3.FL_AUXILIAR = 'FAT'
  AND (FNLP3.FL_SITUACAO = 'C'
  OR FNLP3.FL_SITUACAO = 'G')
  ORDER BY ID_CD_PARCELA DESC)
FROM TB_FIN_LANCAMENTOS_PARC_FNLP FNLP
WHERE FNLP.ID_CD_AUXILIAR = FATU.ID_CD_FATURA
AND FNLP.FL_AUXILIAR = 'FAT'
AND FNLP.FL_CANCELADO = 'N') AS TEM_LANCAMENTO
WHERE ID_CD_FATURA <> '') TB
WHERE (((ID_CD_FATURA_TIPO = '3'
AND IN_STATUS = '1')
AND (ID_CD_FATURA_PRI IS NULL
AND ID_CD_LANCAMENTO IS NULL))
AND ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE <> '')
AND ID_CD_QUEM_RECEBE = @ID_CD_PESSOA
GROUP BY ID_CD_PESSOA,
         DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL,
         NM_PAGREC,
         DS_MOEDA_PRINCIPAL
```

Comment: Verifica aqui, já existe este tópico....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997327/return-0-if-field-is-null-in-mysql

Comment: Como você já utiliza o COALESCE em sua query creio que o título de sua pergunta não reflete a sua verdadeira dúvida.

Comment: Montar tabelas virtuais e fazer um join , me parece a solução      https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/490784-calcular-valores-entre-duas-tabelas/?do=findComment&comment=1950875

Comment: Obrigado Ernesto e Motta, estarei tentando com as dicas que deram. Sr. Anonimo, o ponto é que como pode ver mesmo usando o COALESCE não funcionou para o que eu precisava, essa função só traz o primeiro resultado fora de null que ele encontra, eu preciso que o void, uma consulta inexistente seja trazida como qualquer coisa, ficou claro agora?